# Set an AWS secret from Azure DevOps using a variable from the library variable groups in a release

Tags: azure-devops, aws-secrets-manager

I want to be able to set a variable in a Azure DevOps library and then use it to populate an AWS secret.

In the releases/tasks I see that there is a premade Azure DevOps task "AWS Secrets Manager Create/Update Secret".

Is there anyway I can use a variable I have already set in the Azure DevOps library groups to populate the secret value in the premade task "AWS Secrets Manager Create/Update Secret"?

Comment: Link the Azure DevOps library groups to the release pipeline, then use the `$(variable)` to get the value of that variable.

Comment: Hi friend, How about this question? Could you please give any feedback? If below answer not resolve your question, please let me know the latest information about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, what you need is just refer to this variables (and have variable group added to your pipeline/release)

In YAML it would be just

```yaml
- task: SecretsManagerCreateOrUpdateSecret@1
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'aws'
    regionName: 'eu-west-1'
    secretNameOrId: 'SomeSecret'
    secretValueSource: 'inline'
    secretValue: '$(MyVariable)'
```

and in UI

[image]